# Get template variable inside onRendered in Meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have a template `settings` in which I have an autoform.

I add a hook to my autoform inside the `onRendered` function

```
Template.settings.onRendered( () => {
  AutoForm.addHooks( 'editForm', {
    onSuccess: function( formType, result ) {
      //
    }
  } );
} );
```

How can I, inside my `onSuccess` get a variable populated in the template through `Template.settings.helpers`?

I have tried `Template.instance().variableName`, but it cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

From the Meteor docs:

> In the body of a callback, this is a template instance object that is unique to this occurrence of the template and persists across re-renderings. Use the onCreated and onDestroyed callbacks to perform initialization or clean-up on the object.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered

But I think you need to make use of `function` instead of an ES2015 arrow function or `this` won't be as expected.

Also, you would need to add the line:

`const self = this;`

And then use `self` if you want to access it within the `Autoform` function.